# Make an advent calendar on elementaryOS

Tags: linux, wiki, presentation

I'm trying to make a digital version of an existing paper advent calendar that's a family heirloom. I've looked at the basic online platforms for making an advent calendar and can't find one where I can move the doors around (so they will match the doors on the existing calendar). I'd like to be able to link between a photo of the whole calendar, close-ups of different sections, and each individual door opened. Frosting on top would be including audio recordings.

I've done some basic html and SQL coding in the past, but only working in existing frameworks, not starting from scratch. I'd prefer software where I don't have to do the coding, but wouldn't rule out coding some of it myself if it is simple.

Perhaps a wiki or a non-linear presentation software?

I'm working in elementaryOS and would like something that is also compatible with other operating systems so family can view it.

Answer (score 0):

I am a beginning coder. When I asked this I was struggling to frame the question: How do I make different regions of the same image into separate links?

The answer is by using an image map. This question helped: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18560097/how-to-make-a-section-of-an-image-a-clickable-link

I've since learned to code one for this project: